# Error trying to install a plugin with Cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I'm kinda new to Cordova and cross-platform programming. I've followed a tutorial on the internet but I'm stuck with installing a plugin with plugman. I'd like to use the camera on my app so I tried to run this command line:

```
plugman install --platform android --project hello --plugin cordova-plugin-camera
```

And I get this error message:

```
cordova-android version not detected (lacks script "/Users/XXX/Documents/cordova/hello/hello/cordova/version" ), continuing.
Unable to load PlatformApi from platform. Error: Cannot find module '/Users/XXX/Documents/cordova/hello/hello/cordova/Api.js'
The platform "android" does not appear to be a valid cordova platform. It is missing API.js. android not supported.
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-camera': Error: Your android platform does not have Api.js
```

I've tried a couple of things I saw on forums but I can't find any solution.
I'm running Cordova on version 8.0.0 and have all the requirements needed
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use plugman to install the plugins, use Cordova CLI to install the plugin.

From your project folder, run

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
```

Answer (score 0):

If the project you are working on is Ionic, the command should be:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
```